# Differences between searchable_posts and posts_post in Algolia

Tags: wordpress, algolia

I'm using Algolia Search in Wordpress and I realize that there are duplicated records in *...posts_post* and *...searchable_posts*:

[image]

Does anyone know the difference between them and if they are both necessary?

I would like to remove the duplicate records in one of them.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of a `_posts_post` index. If you're using [this plugin](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/wp-search-with-algolia/wiki/Getting-Started) then you should only need the `_searchable_posts` index, unless there's been customization.